# Essential submodules of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

In [this paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=essential%20exact%20sequences&rlz=1C1YTUH_enUS930US930&oq=essential%20exact%20sequences&aqs=chrome..69i57.4554j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), the authors introduce the notion of essential exact sequences and, in particular, essential submodules.

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is an $R$-module, we say that a submodule $N$ of $M$ is *essential* in $M$ if $N \cap M' \neq 0$ for all nonzero submodules $M'$ of $M$.

There is an example in the paper where, among other items, it's shown that $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is essential in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

With this, I am wondering -- can we say what the essential submodules of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are for general $n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is just a subgroup.

The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ all have the form $m\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $m$ divides $n$, and $$m\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cap k\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \operatorname{lcm}(m,k)\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$

That is, you want to find the divisors $m$ of $n$ such that $n$ divides $k$ whenever $n$ divides $\operatorname{lcm}(m,k)$.  These $m$ are precisely the divisors of $\dfrac{n}{p_1p_2\cdots p_N}$ where the $p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_N$ are the distinct prime divisors of $n$.